# how to position linear progress bar at appbar bottom?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to position linear progress bar at appbar bottom without using the bottom property of the appbar and without inscreasing the appbar height?

like the following image: 
[Material design appbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVHpi.png)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why you don't want to use the bottom property? That is the hook the Flutter `AppBar` widget provides to add things there. Otherwise you have to create your own version of the `AppBar`.

In case it is useful to you, I have created the snippet below that you can use in your appbar like this.

```
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Title"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    bottom: MyLinearProgressIndicator(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ),
```

`MyLinearProgressIndicator` must implement the `preferredSize` getter. That is why you need to create your own version.

```
// Cant't use _kLinearProgressIndicatorHeight 'cause it is private in the
// progress_indicator.dart file
const double _kMyLinearProgressIndicatorHeight = 6.0;

class MyLinearProgressIndicator extends LinearProgressIndicator
    implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  MyLinearProgressIndicator({
    Key key,
    double value,
    Color backgroundColor,
    Animation<Color> valueColor,
  }) : super(
          key: key,
          value: value,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          valueColor: valueColor,
        ) {
    preferredSize = Size(double.infinity, _kMyLinearProgressIndicatorHeight);
  }

  @override
  Size preferredSize;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: In this solution appbar height increases when adding a linear progress bar to the bottom property, which is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 10):

The Simple Way

```
   bottom: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(6.0),
  child: LinearProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),valueColor:new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),value: 0.25,),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

@chemamolins's answer is perfectly valid, but it might be easier just to wrap your widget in a [Preferred Size](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) widget. The widget takes a `child` and a `preferredSize` of type `Size` Here's an example from an app I'm working on, wrapping a StreamBuilder:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 1.0),
              child: ProgressBar(widget.bloc.isLoading),
    ),

---snip---

class ProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Stream<bool> _isLoading;
  ProgressBar(this._isLoading);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _isLoading,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data) {
          return LinearProgressIndicator();
        }
        else {
          return Container();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Chemamolins' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53494660/6696558) is correct, but I feel like `LinearProgressIndicator` is a little thicker than it should be. My version:

```
AppBar(
  title: Text("Title"),
  bottom: _AppBarProgressIndicator()
);
```

The class:

```
const double _kAppBarProgressIndicatorHeight = 4.0;

class _AppBarProgressIndicator extends SizedBox implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  AppBarProgressIndicator({Key key}) : super(
    key: key,
    height: _kAppBarProgressIndicatorHeight,
    child: LinearProgressIndicator()
  );

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size(
    double.infinity,
    _kAppBarProgressIndicatorHeight
  );
}
```

With [Adil Sadik's otimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227281/6696558) it's even better:

```
AppBar(
  title: Text("Title"),
  bottom: _createProgressIndicator()
);
```

The method:

```
PreferredSize _createProgressIndicator() => PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 4.0),
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 4.0,
    child: LinearProgressIndicator()
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Full example here,

Here the linear progress bar is included with in the total height of appbar

You can test it online. copy the whole code and paste it to dartpad :

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: HomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool contactingServer = true; // change this as needed and call setState afterwards

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: appBarWgt(),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }

  appBarWgt() {
    double appBarHeight = 56;
    double progressBarHeight = 5;
    return PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(appBarHeight + progressBarHeight), // here the desired height
      child: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
        titleSpacing: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        bottom: linearProgressBar(progressBarHeight),
      ),
    );
  }

  linearProgressBar(_height) {
    if (!contactingServer) {
      return null;
    }
    return PreferredSize(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: _height,
        child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
      ),
      preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps,

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just use `LinearProgressIndicator()` as the first widget inside a `column`. Then you will get progress Bar below the `Appbar`

```
return Scaffold(
appbar: Appbar(
title: Text('App Bar'),),
body: Column(
children: <widget> [
linearProgressIndicator(),
Text('Hi'),]
),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the easiest way to do this was:

1. Make the App Bar Transparent
2. Set extendBodyBehindAppBar: true for the Widget/Page
3. Place your Linear Indicator as the first widget in your column or container.
4. Wrap your Content in a Safe Area and then bam, it pushes the Linear Indicator under the app bar.

You might even be able to color the app bar, and still have the indicator appear underneath with the safe area method. I didn't try that. I just discovered this by accident. I have posted a similar question except I want mine to appear over top of the AppBar so I am playing with this method right now, so far only successful at placing the indicator below the appbar and not above. But if I can figure out how to consistently set the spacing at the top for all devices I may have a winner with this method which, seems to kindof work for both over top and underneath the appbar.